# finding device via Mac Address

Tags: wireless-networking, mac-address

I have a device in my home network that I am not sure what it is? I know its mac address and find the manufacturer- Aloys, Inc - I use nmap and find its OS :

```
OS CPE: cpe:/o:linux:linux_kernel:2.6

OS details: Linux 2.6.9 - 2.6.30
```

I think it is for my Xcruiser reciver ?! is there any way to find what device it is ?

and its 80 port is open ? and I can reach it via browser but I do not know pass and user name

Comment: If you have a Windows machine you can use, Advanced IP Scanner finds devices on your network, with MAC address and device name (if available).  Famatech makes Advanced IP Scanner.

Comment: ping the device  unplug the network cable from it and see if pings stop?